# Failed Using array_merge inside of PHP class

Tags: php, function, array-merge

```
class Test
{
  public $data = array();

  public function addData($data = array())
  {
    array_merge($data, $this->data);
    return $this;
  }

  public function showData()
  {
    print_r($this->data);
  }
}
$test = new Test;
$test->addData(array("halo", "zaki"))->showData();
```

i tried to merging 2 array, but it doesn't work, maybe someone can explain to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to assign the resulting array to member variable `$data`. It should be,

```
$this->data = array_merge($data, $this->data);
```

Answer (score 2):

`array_merge` does not modify the arrays passed to it, but rather returns the result.

Try this:

```
public function addData($data = array())
{
    $this->data = array_merge($data, $this->data);
    return $this;
}
```